# WPF C# How can I create derived styles by code

Tags: wpf, styles, code-behind

I want to use ListBoxItems which use different contents. For definitions in xaml I use the following approach.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ExampleBaseListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"      />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>   
</Style>


<Style x:Key="ExampleListBoxItem"  TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <ListBoxItem Style="{DynamicResource ExampleBaseListBoxItem}">
                    <TextBox  />
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This works fine, but I have two questions.

1. Is this a good practise of defining in xaml, or should I use 
   sth else?
2. How can I achieve the same result when the style
   ExampleBaseListBoxItem already exists

Please don't worry about the TextBox. I'm looking for a way to do it, the example itself is for demonstration purposes, only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the usual way to approach such things.

You should define styles and templates in xaml rather than code.

But.

It's much more usual to use datatemplates which match a viewmodel type using Datatype= rather than re-templating listboxitem.

The type being that of a row viewmodel.

So you'd have (say) a TextBoxVM class, a DividerVM class etc.

You bind an Observablecollection of object to your itemssource.

Template out a TextBoxVM into a textbox, dividervm into a divider etc.

First examples I happen to have:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DividerVM}">
    <local:Divider />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DrawCategoryVM}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock FontSize="{DynamicResource BigFont}" Text="{Binding Heading}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DrawOptionVM}">
    <Grid Height="38"
          Background="Transparent"
          >
```

You can use basedon to "inherit" attributes of one style into another.

Comment: Thanks Andy, this might be the better approach. But I'm not convinced, yet. As I mentioned in the original post the simple TextBox is just an example. In the real world application, the ControlTemplate of the base ListBoxItem contains serveral components and at one certain location only there is a Contentpresenter. That's why the provided example works. I am wondering if it is possible to reuse all those other components by using the shown approach.

Comment: The datatemplate will apply to the content. The UI it creates will appear where the contentpresenter of the itemtemplate is. You could surround that with whatever you like in the itemtemplate.